# Html.ValidationMessageFor not working with Internet Explorer 8/9

Tags: internet-explorer, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

This is my .cshtml :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.DisplayPrice, new { id = "inputDisplayPrice", data_bind = "value: DisplayPrice" })
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DisplayPrice, string.Empty, new { @class = "validate" })
```

For some reason it works fine with Firefox, but it doesn't show any validation with IE. Is there a workaround?

EDIT:

Fixed. I've added the following references to the .cshtml head, and now works in IE:

```
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script
<script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.7/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
```